# How to suppress stout in tmux run-shell?

Tags: shell, tmux

I have binding in my `.tmux.conf`:

```
bind -n M-W run -b "fish -c \"w #{pane_current_path}\""
```

After shell command run stopped in current pane I get result " Returned 1" as copy mode. How can I suppress that message? I have no way to suppress output to stdout in command, trying to change command to:

```
bind -n M-W run -b "fish -c \"w #{pane_current_path}\" 2> /dev/null" does nothing.
```

From man page I get this:

```
After it finishes, any output to stdout is displayed in copy mode (in the pane specified by -t or the current pane if omitted). If the command doesn't return success, the exit status is also displayed.
```

So I can suppress only redirecting execution to other pane?

Comment: This is not directly an answer, but I solved my problem (which led to this question) with binding to `send-keys "path-to-executable" C-m`. It prints and executes.

Comment: Also `run` doesn't show copy mode if a script doesn't print anything